# Instead of trigger to update view with multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, view, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to find an example of how to update a view on multiple tables using an instead of trigger.

That is I want update more than one table that this view selects from.

I cant find any examples. If someone can show me how to this that would be great.

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres,...) are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're using SQLServer here is one **oversimplified** example

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons
(personid  int, 
 firstname varchar(32), 
 lastname  varchar(32));

CREATE TABLE employees
(employeeid int, 
 personid   int, 
 title      varchar(32));

CREATE VIEW vwEmployees AS
SELECT p.personid, employeeid, firstname, lastname, title
  FROM employees e JOIN persons p
    ON e.personid = p.personid;

CREATE TRIGGER tgEmployeesInsert ON vwEmployees
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO persons (personid, firstname, lastname)
  SELECT personid, firstname, lastname
    FROM INSERTED

  INSERT INTO employees (employeeid, personid, title)
  SELECT employeeid, personid, title
    FROM INSERTED
END;

INSERT INTO vwEmployees (personid, employeeid, firstname, lastname, title)
VALUES(1, 1, 'Jhon', 'Doe', 'SQL Developer');
```

**Note:** In reality you will most certainly have to deal with `IDENTITY` columns and the fact that triggers in SQL Server are statement rather the row scoped.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa4956/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks alot. Can you explain to me what the ramifications of it being statement as opposed to row scoped?

Comment: @AllenHo You're quite welcome :) All your processing in a trigger should be set oriented. You can't count on the fact that you'll get only one row in virtual tables (inserted, deleted) for processing.